# How were Die Entrechteten able to track down Jacob Phelps and the Major?

Tags: the-blacklist

Over the course of a couple of episodes of the second season of *The Blacklist*, starting with episode 14, we see Jacob Phelps on a new assignment from the Major. He infiltrates a neo-nazi group in Dresden, called *Die Entrechteten* (The Disenfranchised). Reddington describes them as a street gang and that is basically how they're portrayed in the series, with the leaders being involved in day-to-day intimidation and dealings.

After Jacob has returned to the USA, we see Die Entrechteten tracking down both him and the Major, of whose existence they didn't even know.

How was a German street gang able to do that? Did they have help?

Answer (score -1):

They definitely needed help, as they cant be well connected, since they struggled even to secure weapons into the country. I believe Red helped them. And that they were merely looking for Jacob,

> and dint know that the Major was Jacob's handler. The Major was referred to simply as "an old man", if i remember correctly.

The gang was merely intent on taking revenge and it was likely Red took advantage of that.

Comment: Do you have any references that back up this assertion?